# Android load a url to the webview that starts with double slash "//"

Tags: android, webview

I am trying to load a youtube video into the webview. The embed link of the video is like the following:

```
//www.youtube.com/embed/sLnBwfWvgpU
```

If i do not do anything extra and just try to load this, the video does not appear in the webview. I tried to do the following:

```
private class CustomWebViewClient extends WebViewClient {
    @Override
    public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
        String url_string = url;
        if(url_string.startsWith("//")){
            url_string = url_string.substring(2);
            if(!url_string.contains("http")){
                url_string = "http://" + url_string;
            }
        }
        webview.loadUrl(url_string);
        return true;
    }
}
```

But that did not work either. I have more content other than this video in my webview and if i do this nothing is loaded and the current content disappears too. So, what can i do about it?

Thanks

Comment: check the value of url that is passed into the method. It probably isn't what you think it is.

Comment: @Henry i actually checked it, here, the url parameter is //www.youtube.com/embed/sLnBwfWvgpU and after i make modifications it becomes http: //www.youtube.com/embed/sLnBwfWvgpU

Comment: Please check the value inside url_string first use logcat and then hit that printed url in pc browser. Check that whether it is working or not.May be you are getting wrong url

Comment: The method should return a boolean. What did you return there?

Comment: @Henry sorry i forgot to write it, it returns true

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should just set javascript;

in your code please try ;

```
private class CustomWebViewClient extends WebViewClient {
@Override
public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
    String url_string = url;
    if(url_string.startsWith("//")){
        url_string = url_string.substring(2);
        if(!url_string.contains("http")){
            url_string = "http://" + url_string;
        }
    }
    webview.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
    webview.loadUrl(url_string);
    return true;
}
}
```

In my codes;

```
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    wb=(WebView)findViewById(R.id.webView1);
    String url_string = "//www.youtube.com/embed/sLnBwfWvgpU";
    if(url_string.startsWith("//")){
        url_string = url_string.substring(2);
        if(!url_string.contains("http")){
            url_string = "http://" + url_string;
        }
    }
    wb.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
    wb.loadUrl(url_string);
```

Comment: thanks but javascript is already enabled for my webview, it can load videos that have the url like http ://www.youtube....... succesfully actually

Comment: So you want to use custom webview ?

Comment: yes, in your code it works but here is the difference: In my webview the youtube video is an iframe tag in the webview, and //www.youtube..... triggers shouldOverrideUrlLoading function after i already call loadUrl().